# pandas pivot_table aggregates on column with boolean values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have the a `df` which looks like,

```
code    y_m       has_id     
1000    201701    True
1000    201701    False
1000    201702    True
1000    201702    True
2000    201701    True
2000    201701    False
2000    201702    False
2000    201702    False
2000    201702    True
```

I first groupby `code` and `y_m` to calculate the percentage of `True` values in each group,

```
df.groupby(['code', 'y_m'])['has_id'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x) / len(x)).reset_index(name='pct_with_id')
```

and then I also want to get a matrix like

```
      0     1     2             3              
 0   -1     0    201701       201702       
 1   0     0.56   0.5          0.6 
 2   1000  0.75   0.5          1.0   
 3   2000  0.4    0.5          0.33
```

-1 represents a dummy value that indicates either a value doesn't exist for a specific code/y_m cell or to maintain matrix shape; `0` represents the percentage of `True` across all `code` or `y_m` or `code` and `y_m`, e.g. cell `(1,1)` is the percentage of `True` for all rows in `df`; `(1,2)` is the percentage of `True` for `201701` across `1000` and `2000` in the `df`.

is it possible to use `pivot_table` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something similar using `pivot_table`

```
dd = pd.pivot_table(
    df, 
    values='has_id', 
    index='code',  
    columns='y_m', 
    margins=True, 
    aggfunc=lambda x: np.sum(x)/len(x)
)
# dd outputs:
y_m   201701    201702       All
code
1000     0.5  1.000000  0.750000
2000     0.5  0.333333  0.400000
All      0.5  0.600000  0.555556
```

Elements can then be accessed using usual pandas method of access. examples:

```
dd.loc[1000, 'All']
# 0.75
dd.loc[1000, 201702]
# 1.0
dd.loc['All', 'All]
# 0.5555555555555556
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for `pivot_table` to work you would need another column that lists the percentage of True for the `pct_with_id`. Then you can specify `values=pct_with_id`, `columns=['y_m']`, `index=['code']`. You may need to make need to make a new entry in code such as `0` to cover your first case of True for all rows.